# React.js onClick event not firing

Tags: reactjs, dom-events

## Problem

I'm trying to understand why my event handler below **navItemClick** isn't firing to the console when an item in the list is clicked. Also, I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to add the onClick event to the NavigationSidebarItem function to reduce repeating it on each item on the return in the NavigationSidebar component.

The component renders correctly; no errors. I also am able to see the console lines for the constructor as well as the JSX loading successfully. Just no clicky clicky message!

## Code Example

```
class NavigationSidebar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.navItemClick = this.navItemClick.bind(this);
        console.log('NavigationSidebar:constructor => success');
    }

    navItemClick(event)
    {
        console.log('this.navItemClick: clicked');
    }

    render()
    {
        return (
                <ul>
                    <NavigationSidebarItem description="Item1" onClick={this.navItemClick} />
                    <NavigationSidebarItem description="Item2" onClick={this.navItemClick} />
                    <NavigationSidebarItem description="Item3" onClick={this.navItemClick} />
                </ul>
        )
    }
};

function NavigationSidebarItem(props) {
    return (
        <li>
            <span>{props.description}</span>
        </li>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <NavigationSidebar/>,
    document.getElementById('navigation-sidebar')
);

console.log('NavigationSidebar.jsx:loaded => finished');
```

Comment: @AndrewL: That results in a ReferenceError: navItemClick is not defined at NavigationSidebar.render. I'm fairly certain the "this" is required to define the scope. Good try though... I haven't felt this stuck in a long time! Especially over something fairly simple... it seems like an elementary React.js example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are possibly confusing the usage/relationship between REACT components and DOM elements written in JSX (within components).

When you bind your `onClick` to `<NavigationSidebarItem />` what you are actually doing is passing a `prop` to the functional component `<NavigationSidebarItem />`, called `props.onClick`. This is not the same as attaching an `onclick` event to a DOM element.

You should pass the `onClick handler` to the component, at which point you will have made `props.<yourOnClickEventHandle>` available to `<NavigationSidebarItem />`.

You then need create your `onClick` on the desired DOM element within the `render` function, which will bind it to the DOM element.

To avoid confusion when returning to the code you should not use the property name `onClick` as it may confuse you later. Say what you mean/intend the method to do and label all event handlers with a familiar structure. e.g. `showMeKittensHandle` (`Handle` being the operative word, not kittens).

```
class NavigationSidebar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.navItemClickHandle = this.navItemClick.bind(this);
        console.log('NavigationSidebar:constructor => success');
    }

    navItemClickHandle(event)
    {
        console.log('this.navItemClick: clicked');
    }

    render()
    {
    console.log(this.navItemClick)
        return (
                <ul>
                    <NavigationSidebarItem description="Item1" navItemClickHandle={this.navItemClickHandle} />
                    <NavigationSidebarItem description="Item2" navItemClickHandle={this.navItemClickHandle} />
                    <NavigationSidebarItem description="Item3" navItemClickHandle={this.navItemClickHandle} />
                </ul>
        )
    }
};

function NavigationSidebarItem(props) {
    return (
        <li onClick={props.navItemClickHandle}>
            <span>{props.description}</span>
        </li>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <NavigationSidebar/>,
    document.getElementById('navigation-sidebar')
);

console.log('NavigationSidebar.jsx:loaded => finished');
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/189598/

Comment: I made these changes; still no console data coming from the navItemClick function. Regarding code cleanliness though, is there no way to eliminate the need for the navClickItem=this.navItemClick?

Also, in your example above, props.navClickItem should be navItemClick. Should it not?

Comment: Also, I've tried is moving the event handling to the sub-component level (e.g. to NavigationSidebarItem instead of NavigationSidebar); however, my understanding with React.js scope is that I will run into troubles determining state for the selected navigation item if I put the code down there. Also, when I tried that, still no event firing even when I tried this method. I should also mention that events do fire correctly in Javascript and that I'm virtually plug-in free.

This example is being rendered client-side using Browser.min.js (no server side stuff just yet).

Comment: Hmm. I am testing this in https://jscomplete.com/repl/ and it is working. With regards to the name, 'No',  once you pass a property to a REACT component via `myPropName="{this.someProp}"`. It will become available on `props` in the component. i.e. `props.myPropName`

Comment: In terms of state in the functional component, that is not it's concern. Class based components manage state functional components only work from the properties they are provided during the cascade of state. That is my understanding.

Comment: I have added a JS fiddle to the solution and switched your console.log to alert for ease. You should see it working now.

Comment: _however, my understanding with React.js scope is that I will run into troubles determining state for the selected navigation item if I put the code down there_ This is a different question. I would make sure you have the fundamental of passing props and binding events before worrying about scopes and state.

Comment: Thanks Chris; that fiddle worked perfectly. I realized afterwards that you had navClickItem and navItemClick which represent slightly different things. I missed updating one of them in my function and when I first read the code I thought it was a typo.

Thank you so much for your help! I don't think I could have gotten there without your guidance -- everyone seems to use React a little differently which makes online examples challenging. Answer accepted!

Comment: Ah, yeah, I did throw it together a little sorry about that. I agree, there are so many different approaches. I don't really use REACT but I have forced myself to use it from time to time just to keep up to date but I do get frustrated with all the different tool chains and approaches, which essentially boil down to variations on a theme. You can't go wrong with the REACT docs from facebook. AirBnB s styleguide is a great resource too.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a click like this:

```
const yourFunction = (arg) => console.log(arg);

<C onClick={(event) => yourFunction('Hello')} />
```

will log Hello when you click;